# Does Django ManyToManyField create table with a redundant index?

Tags: python, mysql, django

If I have a model **Foo** that has a simple M2M field to model **Bar**:

```
class Foo(Model):
    bar = ManyToManyField(Bar)
```

Django seems to create a table **foo_bar** which has the following indices:

```
index 1: primary, unique (id)
index 2: unique (foo_id, bar_id)
index 3: non_unique (foo_id)
index 4: non_unique (bar_id)
```

I recall from my basic knowledge of SQL, that if a query needs to look for conditions on foo_id, index 2 would suffice (since the left-most column can be used for lookup). index 3 seems to be redundant.

Am I correct to assume that index 3 does indeed take up index space while offering no benefit? That I'm better off using a through table and manually create a unique index on (foo_id, bar_id), and optionally, another index on (bar_id) if needed?

Comment: I think that the index 2 is there to prevent duplication. Without it you could have the combination of foo_id and bar_id several times in the table.

Comment: Is it needed? Probably not. Does it matter? No, in 99% of the cases (or 99.9%) it doesn't make a measurable difference. Are you better of doing it yourself? \*cough\* premature optimization \*cough\*... sorry, what was that?

Comment: I understand the need for index2, it is absolutely required here as a compound, unique index. I also get that index 3 does no harm, except possibly taking up memory space, and likely RAM (since indices are best kept in RAM for speedy lookups, right?)  So if it offers no benefit whatsoever, why even create it as a default for all M2M relationships?  Perhaps in some other SQL backend, this is somehow required?

Answer (score 2):

For someone else who is still wondering. This is a known issue and there is an open ticket on the django bug tracker :
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22125

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding how a many-to-many association is represented in the database is to realize that each line of the junction table (in this case, foo_bar) connects one line from the left table (foo) with one line from the right table (bar). Each pk of "foo" can be copied many times to "foo_bar"; each pk of "bar" can also be copied many times to "foo_bar". But the same pair of fk's in "foo_bar" can only occur once.

So if you have only one index (pk of "foo" or "bar") in "foo_bar" it can be only one occurrence of it ... and it is not Many to many relation.

For example we have two models (e-commerce): Product, Order.

Each product can be in many orders and one order can contain many products.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...

class Order(models.Model):
    products = ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderedProduct')


class OrderedProduct(models.Model):
    # each pair can be only one time, so in one order you can calculate price for each product (considering ordered amount of it).
    # and at the same time you can get somewhere in your template|view all orders which contain same product 

    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()  # amount of ordered products
    price = models.IntegerField()  # just int in this simple example

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price = self.product__price * self.amount

        super(OrderedProduct, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```